# maven release:prepare namespace prefix "xsi" collides with an additional namespace declared by the element

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I'm getting this error while I run maven release:prepare on this parent pom.xml. It's a multi-modules maven project.
I tried a lot of things but i still could not fix this, it seems like there is something strange somewhere. I run the same release:prepare on other project and there was no problem.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare failed: The namespace xmlns:xsi="http:
//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" could not be added as a namespace to "project": The namespace prefix "xsi" collides with an additional namespace declared by the element
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more

Caused by: org.jdom.IllegalAddException: The namespace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" could not be added as a namespace to "project": The namespace prefix "xsi" colli
des with an additional namespace declared by the element
```

Do you have any idea where I should look at?

Thank you

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: I updated pom but it's not the full pom (deleted some dependencies, properties)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that one of the multiple module had this **https** instead of **http** but logs didn't mention the cause module

```
    <project
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```